# Request has invalid argument Error on uploading to python Artifact Registry [gcp]

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, python-3.9, artifact, google-artifact-registry

I am trying to upload a python package to GCP's Artifact Registry. I installed `keyring` and `keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth`, added `.pypirc` and `pip.conf` files with the url to the private registry on GCP inside of them, and setup the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` as per this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/python/authentication#keyring-setup).

I created a dummy python package to test the upload to the private pypi.
`python setup.py install` runs successfully.
When running twine:

```
twine upload --verbose -r https://<LOCATION>-python.pkg.dev/<PROJECT_ID>/<REPO_NAME>/ --config-file <PATH_TO_PYPIRC> dist/*
```

I get the following error:

```
Uploading distributions to https://<LOCATION>-python.pkg.dev/<PROJECT_ID>/<REPO_NAME>/
  dist/my_library-0.0.1-py3.9.egg (2.6 KB)
username set from keyring
password set from keyring
username: oauth2accesstoken
password: <hidden>
Uploading my_library-0.0.1-py3.9.egg
100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████| 6.30k/6.30k [00:00<00:00, 47.8kB/s]
Content received from server:
Request has an invalid argument: extension type

HTTPError: 400 Bad Request from https://<LOCATION>-python.pkg.dev/<PROJECT_ID>/<REPO_NAME>/
Bad Request
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using wheel instead of eggs made me upload successfully
`python setup.py bdist_wheel`